# How to set amount of an item dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, payment-gateway

I am trying to integrate a payment gateway on my website. Here is my code

products.php

```
<div class='row footer'>
 <div class='col-5 col-lg-5'>
    <button class='btn btn-action kkiapay-button' 
      amount-price='" . $row['price'] . "' 
      onclick='openKkiapayWidget()'>" . $row['action'] . "
    </button>
 </div>
 <div class='col-7 col-lg-7 price'>
    <span>XOF " . number_format($row['price']) . "</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

main.js

```
openKkiapayWidget({
    amount:"50000",
    position:"center",
    callback:"",
    theme:"red",
    key:"< my-api-key >"
});
```

Now, the problem is that there are many products with different prices; but here I can only put a static amount **(50000)** which applies to all products when the action button is clicked. Is there any way I can dynamically get the price of products and set it in my function in case of a product that has a different price?

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
var price = $(this).amount("price");
openKkiapayWidget({
    amount:""+price+"",
    position:"center",
    callback:"",
    theme:"red",
    key:"<my-api-key>"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the element as argument to a "new" function to handle the price before calling your widget. It can be done using `this` between the parenthesis of the `onclick` function call. Then you will be able to retreive the price from the `amount-price` attribute.

```
<div class='row footer'>
 <div class='col-5 col-lg-5'>
    <button class='btn btn-action kkiapay-button' 
      amount-price='" . $row['price'] . "' 
      onclick='openKkiapayWidgetWithPrice(this)'>" . $row['action'] . "
    </button>
 </div>
 <div class='col-7 col-lg-7 price'>
    <span>XOF " . number_format($row['price']) . "</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

```
function openKkiapayWidgetWithPrice(button)
  let price = button.getAttribute("amount-price");
  
  // The call to your widget
  openKkiapayWidget({
      amount: price,
      position: "center",
      callback: "",
      theme: "red",
      key: "< my-api-key >"
  });
}
```

If `amount-price` includes a currentcy symbol, you have to remove it.